# Cron Job loop getting no information out of mysqli object but print_r says there are rows; works perfectly when running in browser

Tags: php, mysqli, cron

I have a cron job that runs a few mysqli queries and then stores the info in an array for later use. When the cron job runs, the mysqli queries return no syntax errors. I did a print_r of the result and it shows that there were multiple rows in the mysqli object but when the foreach loop ran, no info was extracted from the result object. The funny part? I run the same script in the browser to debug and everything works perfectly. Below is the code. (Browser PHP version 5.7, server/cron PHP version 5.3)

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS, DBNAME);

$emailContent = array();
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM emailType ORDER BY emailNumber");
print_r($result);
foreach($result as $row) {
    print_r($row);
    $emailNumber = $row['emailNumber'];
    $email = array(
        "emailName" => $row['emailName'],
        "emailSlug" => $row['emailSlug'],
        "emailDescription" => $row['emailDescription'],
        "link" => $row['link'],
        "subject" => $row['subject'],
        "content1" => $row['content1'],
        "content2" => $row['content2']
    );
    $emailContent[$emailNumber] = $email;
}
```

I included the return of the print_r methods from above. When running the cron, the print_r($result) returns this:

```
mysqli_result Object
(
    [current_field] => 0
    [field_count] => 16
    [lengths] =>
    [num_rows] => 8
    [type] => 0
)
```

While the print_r($row) returns nothing. When running this through a browser I get the same info print_r($result) but I also get a mysql record for print_r($row). It is important to note that I get no error at all.

Comment: This is interesting, since you try to iterate over that object, which does not make any sense...

Comment: What I am trying to say is: you _cannot_ iterate over that returned object. You have to use that object to fetch the rows using the methods the object provides.  Your `print_r()` call clearly shows that there are no "rows" inside the object the `foreach` loop could iterate over. Please take a look at a few examples to learn how to use that mysql connector.

Comment: Not sure what you see when executing that script in a request triggered by your browser, but certainly _not_ an entry in that database table.

Comment: I'm just starting to go from procedural to oop so using objects is very new to me. So, @arkascha you're saying I should use something like `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())` to get the information out of the object?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I demonstrate in the answer I posted below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Extending my comments to the question here is a simple example to demonstrate how to correctly use that object you get returned, when running in query:

```
<?php
// ...
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM emailType ORDER BY emailNumber");
print_r($result);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    print_r($row);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: That fixed it. I'm still learning how to properly use objects. I tried checking out the php manual but that thing confuses me more than I'd like to admit. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could be of help! It is a good thing that you read the php documentation (I hope the real one at php.net...). Most people don't do that, only rely on some questionable third party explanations and are frustrated if things don't work out as expected. Stick with the original documentation, you will get used to the compact and precise style.